# JAX-RS: Shared variables per request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Working on a JAX-RS application. I have an endpoint (@GET). Once the request arrives at endpoint, the call stack flows through multiple service classes.
As shown in below image. I want something in place of that RED Bucket.

[image]

Is there any I can create a shared session map which lives only per request?

I considered using STATIC or @Singleton but these values are shared between multiple requests. I don't want that.

Please point me to right question

Comment: what's your jax-rs implementations?

Comment: What about using a `ThreadLocal` variable?

Comment: It may depend on how this shared resource is created. Can it be built with information from the request? Maybe a custom CDI producer that creates the resource based on the request-context and injects it into your services would fit your requirements. 
If the resource can only be created by your `BurgerBuilderService` and all other services depend on it, it may be better to "forward" it as method-parameter to singal that the following services depend on this resource.

Comment: What's wrong with a `@RequestScoped` component?

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a scoping question.  This may provide an answer to your question:

[How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Ha Ha Ha....
This is so weird Have you seen the answers on that question? It was I who answered that question. But I answered it for JSF not for JAX-RS and I guess it works here as well.